# not able to approve the contract for safeTransfer

Tags: solidity, erc-721

```
pragma solidity 0.8;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/utils/ERC721Holder.sol";

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract TokenTicket1 is ERC721Holder{

     IERC721 public Token;

     constructor (address _token) public {
         Token = IERC721(_token);
     }

     function _approval(uint id) external{
         Token.approve(address(this), id);
     }

     
     function deposit(uint id) external{
         Token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), id);
         
     }
     
     function withdraw(uint Id) external{
         Token.safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, Id);
     }
     
}
```

token address ---> https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0x5ff5a01a288c44f5bacab3291532a74c16642556

This is the error I get: [image]

Comment: Welcome! We usually recommend putting the text of errors in a code block(put ``` before and after) instead of screenshots, which we try to avoid wherever possible. You may also want to put a bit of text in the question describing the problem (instead of relying on the title). This will all help people have an easier time answering!

Answer (score 1):

This line `Token.approve(address(this), id)` is wrong. It requesting to Token to approve the contract itself, which is not needed.

The intention should be that msg.sender request to Token to approve the contract. That operation cannot be coded in the contract it has to be explicitly done by the user.

In javascript it will be

```
Token.approve(TokenTicket1_address, ID).send({from: user_address})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you verify your contract in etherscan.io, the contract code won't be readable for anyone.

You are using an interface to access an ERC721 contract. Does that contract have any `mint()` function to create tokens? who are currently the token owners?

You didn't mention which function call is giving you this error, but I guess it is the `approve()` one, and is telling you that the caller of this function does not own the token or doesn't have the approval role.

The `approval()` and `deposit()` functions you currently have in this contract will only work if a token has been previously minted to the account that is executing these functions.